# Norm of a sequence

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

The following is a theorem that I have some difficulty at it.

[image]
[image]

I do not know how the author shows that $\alpha \in \ell^1$. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please define the spaces in question.

Comment: @T.A.E. : $\omega \in K(H)^*$

Comment: That still does not help. Can you describe in words?

Comment: @T.A.E. :  $K(H)$ is the compact operator space and $\omega:K(H) \to \Bbb C$ is the bounded linear functional on compact operator space.

Answer (score 0):

The property that the author is using is that, for a sequence $\alpha$,
$$
\|\alpha\|_1=\sup\{\,|\langle \alpha,\beta\rangle|\,:\ \|\beta\|_\infty=1\,\}.
$$
This is easily shown. Note that, by Hölder, if $\|\beta\|_\infty=1$, then 
$$
|\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle|\leq\|\alpha\|_1\,\|\beta\|_\infty=\|\alpha\|_1.
$$
And  $\|\alpha\|_1=\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle$ where $\beta_n$ is the complex number of absolute value one such that $\beta_n\alpha_n=|\alpha_n|$.

Comment: How does he define $(\alpha,\beta)$?

Comment: The reason T.A.E. is asking those questions above is that here you are expected to type your question; one advantage of this is that it makes sure you read the text you are quoting.  From the page you posted: "... so that we can **define** $$\langle \alpha,\beta\rangle=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\alpha_n\beta_n. "$$

Comment: I know he defines it as above. But I think $\alpha$ is fixed and then define The functional $\phi_\alpha: c_0 \to \Bbb C$ such that $\phi_\alpha(\beta) = \sum \alpha_n\beta_n$, while you used $(\ell^1)^* = \ell^\infty$ to your above argument which confused me.

Comment: I see. But that's interpretation. And I didn't use duality. The symbol $\langle\alpha, \beta\rangle $ means that, no theory is needed; only some some condition on the sequences that guarantees convergence. In fact, $(\ell^1)^*=\ell^\infty $ is a CONSEQUENCE of defining $\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle $ like that (who says that a bounded functional on $\ell^1$ is a sequence? ).